# How to expand data frame to show each date

Tags: r, dataframe, date

I have a data frame of start dates and end dates. I'm looking to expand the data frame so I can view each date between the 2 dates.

original df:

| start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- |
| 1-5-2023 | 1-10-2023 |
| 2-3-2023 | 2-10-2023 |

new df:

| start_date | end_date | current_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1-5-2023 | 1-10-2023 | 1-5-2023 |
| 1-5-2023 | 1-10-2023 | 1-6-2023 |
| 1-5-2023 | 1-10-2023 | 1-7-2023 |
| 1-5-2023 | 1-10-2023 | 1-8-2023 |
| 1-5-2023 | 1-10-2023 | 1-9-2023 |
| 1-5-2023 | 1-10-2023 | 1-10-2023 |
| 2-3-2023 | 2-10-2023 | 2-3-2023 |
| 2-3-2023 | 2-10-2023 | 2-4-2023 |
| 2-3-2023 | 2-10-2023 | 2-5-2023 |
| 2-3-2023 | 2-10-2023 | 2-6-2023 |
| 2-3-2023 | 2-10-2023 | 2-7-2023 |
| 2-3-2023 | 2-10-2023 | 2-8-2023 |
| 2-3-2023 | 2-10-2023 | 2-9-2023 |
| 2-3-2023 | 2-10-2023 | 2-10-2023 |

Answer (score 0):

How about this, you can use `reframe()` to make a sequence between the start and end dates.

```r
library(dplyr)
dat <- tibble::tribble(
  ~start_date,  ~end_date,
"1-5-2023", "1-10-2023",
"2-3-2023", "2-10-2023")
dat %>% 
  mutate(across(c(start_date, end_date), lubridate::mdy)) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  reframe(start_date = start_date, 
          end_date = end_date, 
          curent_date = seq(start_date, end_date, by="1 day"))
#> # A tibble: 14 × 3
#>    start_date end_date   curent_date
#>    <date>     <date>     <date>     
#>  1 2023-01-05 2023-01-10 2023-01-05 
#>  2 2023-01-05 2023-01-10 2023-01-06 
#>  3 2023-01-05 2023-01-10 2023-01-07 
#>  4 2023-01-05 2023-01-10 2023-01-08 
#>  5 2023-01-05 2023-01-10 2023-01-09 
#>  6 2023-01-05 2023-01-10 2023-01-10 
#>  7 2023-02-03 2023-02-10 2023-02-03 
#>  8 2023-02-03 2023-02-10 2023-02-04 
#>  9 2023-02-03 2023-02-10 2023-02-05 
#> 10 2023-02-03 2023-02-10 2023-02-06 
#> 11 2023-02-03 2023-02-10 2023-02-07 
#> 12 2023-02-03 2023-02-10 2023-02-08 
#> 13 2023-02-03 2023-02-10 2023-02-09 
#> 14 2023-02-03 2023-02-10 2023-02-10
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-07 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

```
library(data.table)

f <- \(s,e) seq(s,e,1)

setDT(df) %>% 
  .[,lapply(.SD, as.IDate, "%m-%d-%y")] %>% 
  .[,.(current_date=f(start_date, end_date)), .(start_date,end_date)]
```

Output:

```
    start_date   end_date current_date
        <IDat>     <IDat>       <IDat>
 1: 2020-01-05 2020-01-10   2020-01-05
 2: 2020-01-05 2020-01-10   2020-01-06
 3: 2020-01-05 2020-01-10   2020-01-07
 4: 2020-01-05 2020-01-10   2020-01-08
 5: 2020-01-05 2020-01-10   2020-01-09
 6: 2020-01-05 2020-01-10   2020-01-10
 7: 2020-02-03 2020-02-10   2020-02-03
 8: 2020-02-03 2020-02-10   2020-02-04
 9: 2020-02-03 2020-02-10   2020-02-05
10: 2020-02-03 2020-02-10   2020-02-06
11: 2020-02-03 2020-02-10   2020-02-07
12: 2020-02-03 2020-02-10   2020-02-08
13: 2020-02-03 2020-02-10   2020-02-09
14: 2020-02-03 2020-02-10   2020-02-10
```

Comment: i'm getting an error for this line: f <- \(s,e) seq(s,e,1)

Comment: If you have R version less than 4.1, you may not use the shorthand `\(s,e)`. Instead, use `function(s,e)`

Answer (score 0):

My package timeplyr can do time expansions quite easily, though it generally works best with "long" data.

```r
# remotes::install_github("NicChr/timeplyr")
library(timeplyr, quietly = TRUE)
library(dplyr, quietly = TRUE)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(lubridate, quietly = TRUE)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date, intersect, setdiff, union
df <- tibble(start_date = c(ydm("2023-05-01"),
                            ydm("2023-03-02")),
             end_date = c(ydm("2023-10-01"),
                          ydm("2023-10-02")),
             group = c("A", "B"))

df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  time_expand(start_date, end_date, 
              time = across(start_date, .names = "current_date"), 
              from = start_date, to = end_date,
              by = "day")
#> # A tibble: 14 x 4
#> # Groups:   group [2]
#>    group current_date start_date end_date  
#>  * <chr> <date>       <date>     <date>    
#>  1 A     2023-01-05   2023-01-05 2023-01-10
#>  2 A     2023-01-06   2023-01-05 2023-01-10
#>  3 A     2023-01-07   2023-01-05 2023-01-10
#>  4 A     2023-01-08   2023-01-05 2023-01-10
#>  5 A     2023-01-09   2023-01-05 2023-01-10
#>  6 A     2023-01-10   2023-01-05 2023-01-10
#>  7 B     2023-02-03   2023-02-03 2023-02-10
#>  8 B     2023-02-04   2023-02-03 2023-02-10
#>  9 B     2023-02-05   2023-02-03 2023-02-10
#> 10 B     2023-02-06   2023-02-03 2023-02-10
#> 11 B     2023-02-07   2023-02-03 2023-02-10
#> 12 B     2023-02-08   2023-02-03 2023-02-10
#> 13 B     2023-02-09   2023-02-03 2023-02-10
#> 14 B     2023-02-10   2023-02-03 2023-02-10
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>